# I have a question about mantra?

Tags: mantra

Is it bad to do my mantra backwards? I say it normally, just I have been moving the beads backwards. Should I move them forward?

Comment: Are you practising in a particular tradition, and do you have a teacher?

Comment: I was new to mantra and Buddhism. And I showed some of the other people who are practicing Buddhism, and they said that I’m doing it wrong I was doing it counter clockwise, and they told me I should be doing it clockwise. What do you mean particular tradition? Would you call the other people who practice Buddhism teacher because they did teach me. I’m a paraplegic in a wheelchair and in my city I couldn’t find a temple that is wheelchair accessible.